# How to define objects of mixed type in flow, then assign objects with a more definite type?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Using Flow, I would like to define a type for an object that can have any keys, whose values may hold string, number, or boolean.

Elsewhere I would like to define multiple more specific types that can act a sub-types, which still conform to this type, but define specific keys and value types.

*(By "sub-type" I do not mean a specific Flow terminology...)*

```js
export type Fields = { [key: string]: string | number | boolean };
export type MyFields = { foo: string };

const myFields: MyFields = { foo: 'bar' };
let fields: Fields = myFields;
```

Why does this result in the following errors? And, what is a better way to do this?

```
Cannot assign `myFields` to `fields` because  string is incompatible with  number in property `foo`. Flow(InferError)

Cannot assign `myFields` to `fields` because  string is incompatible with  boolean in property `foo`. Flow(InferError)
```

Comment: Unsound because now you can change `foo` to `boolean` or `number` and in some other place in code treat the reference as  `{ foo: string }`. You could make the wider type readonly https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiCmAPADrATgF1LgJ4YqgBiAlitACYDOoAvKAN6gDUA2gNYqEBcoOrmwUAdgHMAuoOGjJoAD6gxAVwC2AIxTYloTbFjQUAQzGgAvgG5UmHPiIlQAWUKVq9Jq2WRDskeISStbIAMawYsKg6m5UtHSCru7xXmy+sIIA5Jom2JkhxviQcfSCyZ7MMeV0VkA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aleksey's suggestion is what worked for me – Marking the fields within my object as [read-only](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-readonly).

```
export type Fields = { +[key: string]: string | number | boolean };
```